# How to show the names of extracted features, in Autoencoders

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, autoencoder

**I'm working on a neural network, called Autoencoders to extract the features from NASA's dataset**
*The problem I'm facing is the display of names of extracted features.*

```
class AutoEncoders(Model):
    def __init__(self, output_units):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = Sequential(
            [
              Dense(32, activation="relu"),
              Dense(16, activation="relu"),
              Dense(7, activation="relu")
            ]
        )

        self.decoder = Sequential(
            [
              Dense(16, activation="relu"),
              Dense(32, activation="relu"),
              Dense(output_units, activation="sigmoid")
            ]
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        encoded = self.encoder(inputs)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded


auto_encoder = AutoEncoders(len(x_train_scaled.columns))

auto_encoder.compile(
    loss='mae',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    optimizer='adam'
)


history = auto_encoder.fit(
    x_train_scaled, 
    x_train_scaled, 
    epochs=15, 
    batch_size=32, 
    validation_data=(x_test_scaled, x_test_scaled)
    )
```

**Down Here is the code showing the extracted features.**
*I want to get the names of the extracted features.*

```
encoder_layer = auto_encoder.get_layer('sequential')
reduced_df = pd.DataFrame(encoder_layer.predict(x_test_scaled))
reduced_df = reduced_df.add_prefix('feature_')
display(reduced_df)
```

Comment: You need a list of names. when the model predicts, finding the name from list base predicting features.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna try it....!

Comment: Did you win? I face a similar problem. I needed to cluster my feature names according to their encoded groups.

Comment: I asked and answered a related question, regarding this.
you can visit the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69244021/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-7-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected